# How to create a Dynamic Reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, reducers

I have this `object` in my state from the *Redux Store*:

```
 altaUsuario: {
    //identificacion
    identificacion : {
      email:  '',
      username: '',      
    },
    //Localización
    localizacion : {     
      direccion: '',
      cp: '', 
      provincia: '',
    },
    //Redes sociales
    rdSocial : [
      { 
        red:"", 
        name:""
      },
    ],
```

Let's say that I have three steps on my form, and each of them updates a specific section, so I call an action for update *identification* other action for update *localizacion* and the last one for update *rdSocial*, (Sorry for the Spanish variables). 
The important part here is the payload from each action, which is a piece of the entire `altaUsuario` object, for example, this is one of my actions:

```
{
  type: 'ADD_ID_FIELDS',
  payload: {
    email: '',
    username: 'josue',
  }
}
```

Now, my reducer makes a copy from the state object and update the *altaUsuario* property, with the update of the specific part of the object that I want to update. (It sound confusing) Lets see how I am doing it:

```
    case ADD_ID_FIELDS: 
      return { ...state, altaUsuario : {...state.altaUsuario, identificacion :action.payload }}
    case ADD_LOCAL_FIELDS: 
      return { ...state, altaUsuario : {...state.altaUsuario, localizacion :action.payload }}
    case ADD_RD_SOCIAL: 
      return { ...state, altaUsuario : { ...state.altaUsuario, rdSocial : action.payload}}
    default:
```

> **So, How could I automate this process in one single action?**

This is what I have so far, But it doesn't work:

```
case ADD_FIELD: 
      Object.keys(state.altaUsuario).map (cat => { 
          if(Object.keys(action.payload).some(r=> Object.keys(state.altaUsuario[cat]).includes(r))){                  
            return { ...state, altaUsuario : {...state.altaUsuario, [cat] :action.payload }}
          }
      })
```

My idea was to make a search inside the *altaUsuario* with the specific property that I want to update, but it doesn't work.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current reducer, action ID (ADD_ID_FIELDS, ADD_LOCAL_FIELDS, ADD_RD_SOCIAL) determines which field is going to be updated (identificacion, localizacion, rdSocial).

So in order to make you approach work, you would need to pass in which parameter to update when you are executing action. E.g. as part of action. Something like this:

```
case "ADD_FIELD":
    return { ...state, altaUsuario: {...state.altaUsuario, [action.fieldToUpdate]: action.payload }};
```

Action call would look something like:

```
export const addField = (payload, id) => dispatch => 
    dispatch({ type: ADD_FIELD, fieldToUpdate: id, payload })
```

Comment: So, according to this, my action should be something like this: `export const addField = (payload, fieldToUpdate) => ({ type: ADD_FIELD, fieldToUpdate, payload })`

Comment: Something like that. I updated my answer to be more precise.